# After adding navigation drawer to an activity, the in activity swipe doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, swipe

I intended to add a navigation drawer to my app and finally used [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) treehouse post to create one. But after adding the navigation drawer to my app then the swipes i perform in the activity seems to be neglected or not recognized by the app. Can anybody explain to me why this is happening.And a possible solution for this problem.

Comment: "The swipes I perform in the activity" are these all swipes? Swipes from the edge to open the nav drawer?

Comment: Yes it includes all swipes.

Comment: Does your activity receive any touch events at all?

Comment: Yes I have used on gesture detector and have on touch event

Comment: Could you post some of your code? I'd like to see your Activity code and the activity layout file.

Comment: I have only used on fling method in gesture detector class I have only left and right swipe in the app

Comment: Again, please post your code. That's the only way I can help you.

Comment: You can view the app here: https://plus.google.com/communities/108237772011937004893

Comment: Code, not a compiled APK :)

Comment: Sorry friend am right now not at home will post the code as soon as I get home.. I shared the apk link link so that you could see the features I used in my app..